# Chapter 6 of RailsTutorial.org by Michael Hartl Rspec Blank Email check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

In [chapter 6.x](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#code-validates_email_spec) of the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl, I can't get Rspec to pass the `email is not present` check.

From my limited knowledge:

- the User_spec creates a test user using the code after before do.
- This user is then checked against the attributes in `user.rb` to make
  sure the `:presence` is valid.
- The check then returns true or false if its valid.
- In the next code, before { @user.email = " " } sets the email to
  empty
- then says `it { should_not be_valid }`

However, it fails `User when email is not present` error.

`/spec/models/User_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

`spec/models/user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

Failures:

> 1) User when email is not present 
>            Failure/Error: it { should_not be_valid }
>              expected # not to be valid
>            # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in '
>
> ```
> Finished in 0.03278 seconds
> 4 examples, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18 # User when email is not present
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're validating the email as being present, which means that it would fail if the value is nil or an empty string.

In your rspec block that describes the case where the email should not be present, you're defining the email address as a string consisting of a single space. You actually want to make that a blank string, by removing the space:

```
before { @user.email = "" }
```

That will now fail the validation.

Comment: A blank string is different than a empty string, am I correct? So would email = ""} just check for a blank box and not if the email is empty? Do I make any sense? haha

Comment: Well I'd use blank and empty to mean the same thing, as a space is still a character. The string in your example was `" "` - note the space. According to rails, that's a non-empty string, and it's also not blank.

Comment: Clarification: In rails, `"".blank? == "".empty? == true`, but `" ".blank? == true; " ".empty? == false`!! In other words, a string containing a space **is blank**, but is **not empty**.